# attr_accesor method for write classes in ruby

Tags: ruby

need help, I want to use the "attr_accesor" method to save space in the code and use it instead of "get_value" and "set_value", but how?

If the code is:

```
class Thing
    def initialize(aName, aDescription)
        @name = aName
        @description = aDescription
    end

    def get_name
        return @name
    end

    def set_name(aName)
        @name = aName
    end

    def get_description
        return @description
    end

    def set_description(aDescription)
        @description = aDescription
    end
end

class Treasure < Thing
    def initialize(aName, aDescription, aValue)
        super(aName, aDescription)
        @value = aValue.to_f
    end

    def get_value
        return @value
    end

    def set_value(aValue)
        @value = aValue.to_f
    end
end

t1 = Thing.new("Rock", "costless thing")
puts "Name: #{t1.get_name}"
puts "Description: #{t1.get_description}"

puts ""
puts "Treasure"
t2 = Treasure.new("Nugget", "A gold Nugget", "50000")
puts "Name: #{t2.get_name}"
puts "Description: #{t2.get_description}"
puts "Value: #{t2.get_value}"
```

Can you tell how to rewrite Thing and Treasure classes using attr_accesor method?

Comment: Use two spaces for indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add them to your class definition, for `Thing` class you need to add

```
attr_accessor :name, :description
```

and for `Treausre` class you need,

```
attr_accessor :value
```

and it will expose both getter and setter methods in your class,

If you just need to define getter or setter you can use the following,

```
attr_reader -> getter method
attr_writer -> setter method
```

your classes should now look like

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :name, :description

  def initialize(name, description)
    @name = name
    @description = description
  end
end

class Treasure < Thing
  attr_accessor :value

  def initialize(name, description, value)
    super(name, description)
    @value = value.to_f
  end
end
```

Now you can do things like

```
t1 = Thing.new("Rock", "costless thing")
puts "Name: #{t1.name}"
puts "Description: #{t1.description}"

puts ""
puts "Treasure"
t2 = Treasure.new("Nugget", "A gold Nugget", "50000")
puts "Name: #{t2.name}"
puts "Description: #{t2.description}"
puts "Value: #{t2.value}"
```

Comment: If you are using `attr_accessor :name`, you don't need to do `@name = aName`. Do `self.name = aName` instead. Also, please mention naming conventions for variables. `aName` can be simply `name`.

Comment: This code behaves slightly different than `Treasure#set_value`. In original code, you convert the value to float before assigning. With `attr_accessor`, that is not possible.

Comment: ok, for the code:
t1 = Thing.new("Rock", "costless thing")
puts "Name: #{t1.get_name}"
puts "Description: #{t1.get_description}"
What could be the reorder to use the new class "Thing"?

Comment: I think you are correct about the float conversion but I think its better to use @ notation instead of self. because self. could get confusing if OP writes an instance method name to maybe format with name in some way

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with float, the initialize block takes care of it

Comment: `self.note=` is about twice as slow as `@note=` in most situations, although these speed comparisons are relative where each is fast and the difference would be negligible in any application. I personally prefer the `@note=` syntax unless there is any additional logic in the setter, but I am uncertain what the "convention" or "accepted" way is

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the already good answer here, `attr_accessor` is really nothing more than a shortcut to define those getter and setter methods for you.

This:

```
attr_accessor :index
```

Will literally do this for you without any additional code:

```
def index
  return @index
end

def index=(value)
  @index = value
end
```

If you are familiar with `C` languages, think of it as a macro for defining basic getter and setters for you without the extra typing. As already stated, the `attr_reader` will define a getter only, `attr_writer` a setter only, while `attr_accessor` does both.

Note that none of these will actually define the instance variable `@index` simply by placing them in your code, that will still need done elsewhere in your code, such as `@index = -1` in your `initialize` method (or wherever is most appropriate in your code) if you need a "default" value.